# Number plate lights not working

Tags: electrical

Hi I have a one year old Motorhome, the number plate lights have corroded beyond repair. I am waiting for the to be repaired under warranty. Does this mean technically my Motorhome off the road as I had already been informed one night that they were not working by a policeman?

Comment: Are you asking if you should take it off the road until it's repaired?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the law in your jurisdiction - in the UK, it is illegal to drive any vehicle with any non-functioning lights - although this doesn't seem to be enforced much, jusging by the number of people driving round with only one working headlamp...

As you've used the British term 'number plate' rather than the American 'licence plate', I'm guessing you are over here, and so yes, your motorhome is technically not roadworthy until it is fixed.